# How to replace delimited words in regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a underscore delimited string or words such as:
`word1_word2_word3_word4` and a list of allowed values such as `word1, word3`
The goal is to filter out not allowed values and replace them with let's say … so the resulting string will be `word1_..._word3_...`
This needs to be done in MySQL and I plan to use REGEXP_REPLACE but all my attempts to come with a working regex that handles all instances ( such as first and last word) failed.

To simplify things I tried adding a leading and trailing underscores to the string so it becomes `_word1_word2_word3_word4_` and do:
`(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)` which nicely matches all string between delimiters, however I could not figure out how to exclude word1 and word3.

Comment: `word4` currently does not have a `_` after it, is that intentional? It won't match

Comment: 8.0 has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, are you using that version?

Answer (score 3):

Just negative lookahead for `word1|word3` right before the start of the match:

```
(?<=_)(?!word1|word3)[^_]+(?=_)
```

If the match may also start at the beginning of the string or end at the end of the string (without a `_` delimiter), then alternate the lookarounds with `^` and `$`:

```
(?<=_|^)(?!word1|word3)[^_]+(?=_|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/QFb1p7/1

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<![^_])(?!(?:word1|word3)(?![^_]))[^_]+(?![^_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uBKA5l/1).

Note: `(?<![^_])` = `(?<=^|_)` and `(?![^_])` = `(?=_|$)`, but are more efficient. Why `(?![^_])` in `(?!(?:word1|word3)(?![^_]))` is used? Because you may still want to match `word10` or `word345`.

**Details**

- `(?<![^_])` - start of string or `_`
- `(?!(?:word1|word3)(?![^_]))` - no `word1` or `word3` up to the end of string or `_` are allowed
- `[^_]+` - 1+ chars other than underscores
- `(?![^_])` - end of string or `_`